# locally doubling measure

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\mu, d$ be a measure and the Euclidean metric on $[0,\infty)$.

Recall that a measure $\mu$ is locally doubling measure if for each $x\in [0,\infty)$ there exists a constant  $C_x>0, r_x>0$ (only depend on $x$) such that $$ \mu(B(y,2r))\leq C_x \mu(B(y,r))$$ for all balls $B(y,2r)\subset B(x,r_x)$, where $B(x,r):=\{y\in [0,\infty):d(x,y)<r\}$.

We say that $([0,\infty),\mu,d)$ supports a locally $p$-Poincare inequality (where $\infty>p>1$) if for each $x\in [0,\infty)$ there exists a constant $C_x>0,r_x>0$ (only depend on $x$) such that $$\frac{1}{\mu(B(y,r))}\int_{B(y,r)}\left|u(t)-\int_{B(y,r)}u(s)d\mu(s)\right|d\mu(t)\leq C_x r\left(\frac{1}{\mu(B(y,r))}\int_{B(y,r)}|\nabla u|^pd\mu\right)^{1/p} $$
for all functions $u\in W^{1,p}([0,\infty))$ , for all balls $B(y,r)\subset B(x,r_x)$ where $W^{1,p}([0,\infty))$ is the Sobolev space on $[0,\infty)$.

---

It is well known that there exists $([0,\infty),\mu,d)$ supports a global $p$-Poincare inequality but $\mu$ is not global doubling. (See Example 4 in ArXiv: 1902.10876).

Then I would like to known how about in locally case. It means that: **Is there $\mu$ with locally $p$-Poincare inequality but not locally doubling ?**

In the locally case: We know that locally A_p-weights if and only if locally doubling and locally $p$-Poincare inequality. (see Theorem 1.2 in ArXiv:1807.02174)

I am trying to find an example $\mu(x)=x^\alpha dx$ with locally $p$-Poincare inequality and not locally A_p-weights. But it does not work because if $\alpha >p-1$ then $\mu$ not locally A_p-weights (from definition), and $\alpha<0$ then $\mu$ is locally $p$-Poincare inequality from modifying Example 4 in ArXiv:1902.10876. Can you help me ?

Comment: If this questions does not receive any answer here, I think it would be well-suited for Mathoverflow (be sure to mention that it's a crosspost).